# Vector in a linearly dependent set is a linear combination of other vectors in that set?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a true/false HW problem:

If $S$ = {$v_{1}$, $v_{2}$, . . . $v_{n}$} is linearly dependent then any $v_{k}$, inf ≥ *k* ≥ 1, is a combination of the other vectors in $S$.

The setup I did is:

$v_{k}$ = -($a_1/a_k$)$v_1$ - ($a_2/a_k$)$v_2$ - . . . - ($a_{k-1}/a_k$)$v_{k-1}$ - ($a_{k+1}/a_k$)$v_{k+1}$ - . . . - ($a_{n}/a_k$)$v_{n}$

Since at least one of the $a$ terms must not be zero because $S$ is linearly dependent $v_{k}$ seems to me to be possibly the linear combination of the other terms in $S$. However, I know that linear dependence requires only one of the vectors to be a combination of the preceding vectors in its vector space, so that leads me to believe that while $v_k$ could be a linear combination of the other vectors in $S$ it doesn't need to be. I don't have a good idea on where to go from here.

Comment: @FlybyNight no dimension is given in the problem. Was your comment supposed to be leading me to something?

Comment: $\{(1,0),(2,0),(0,1)\}$.

Comment: The title is a bit unclear, by the way.  It should refer to linearly dependent _sets_ in a vector space, rather than linearly dependent vector spaces.

Comment: @TrevorWilson tried to update the title to make it clearer

Comment: When you write "$\text{inf} \ge k \ge 1$", do you mean $k \ge 1$ or do you want to allow an infinite dimensional vector space? The notations $k \ge 1$ and $1 \le k < \infty$ mean the same.

Comment: @FlybyNight I believe it is the former--an infinite dimensional vector space, though I copied that part of the question nearly verbatim from the assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $S:=\{0,v\}$ where $v\ne 0$. It is linearly dependent, but $v\ne \lambda\cdot 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Consider $n = 3$.  What if $v_2 = 2v_1$?  That doesn't put any restrictions on what $v_3$ can be.