# in a linearly dependent set there exist a vector which is a linear combination of finite number of other vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm watching [Linear Independence and Subspaces](https://youtu.be/eNzK7mVRWT4?t=30m41s) lecture, and the prof proves that in any linear dependent space there's a vector which is a linear combination of finite number of other vectors.

He looks at $\alpha_1*x_1 + ...+ \alpha_n*x_n = \theta$, finds the largest index `k` of a non-zero coefficient $\alpha_k$, and shows that we can express $x_k$ as a l.c of the previous vectors like so: $-\alpha_1/\alpha_k*x1 + ... + -\alpha_{k-1}/\alpha_k*x_{k-1} = x_k$

HOWEVER, it might be that $\alpha_k$ is the ONLY one which isn't zero! so $\alpha_1 .. \alpha_{k-1}$ are *all* zero! how do we deal with that???

related to [Vector in a linearly dependent set is a linear combination of other vectors in that set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542207/vector-in-a-linearly-dependent-set-is-a-linear-combination-of-other-vectors-in-t), but here I'm after just one vector, not every vector in the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha_k$ is the only nonzero coefficient, we have that $x_k=0$, thus any set containing it is linearly dependent.

Comment: do you mean that if xk is the zero vector, we can represent it as a trivial linear combination of other vectors, with all coefficients zero? does that count as a legit linear combination?

Comment: Yes, it does, a linear combination is just a sum of vectors multiplied by scalars, whichever those scalars are.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem if only one $\alpha$ is nonzero. It is still a linear combination of the other vectors. For a concrete example, consider $(1,0), (0,1), (2,0)$. These are three vectors in a two-dimensional space, and so are certainly linearly dependent. The linear dependence relation here is that $(2,0) = 2 (1,0) + 0 (0,1)$.

Comment: thanks @mixedmath - I wasn't clear on my question, tried to rephrase. I'm not worried that one of the coefficients in the linear combination would be 0, I'm worried that they all would be zero!

Comment: @ihadanny I've addressed that in my answer.